# Insert closing brace when changing function from one-liner to multi-line vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, curly-braces

I'm certain IntelliJ did this for me by default, but in VS Code I would like to find there is a built-in auto-insert for a closing brace when going from code sample 1 (one-liner) to code sample 2 (multi-line).

```
if (true) doStuff();
```

Now, for whatever reason, I want the above to be multi-line. I goto the end of the if and hit `{` followed by `Enter`.
I get an incomplete if (with no closing brace):

```
if (true) {
    doStuff();
```

What I want is this:

```
if (true) {
    doStuff();
}
```

I apologize as I [often] cannot come up with the right words for the question, but basically, I think IntelliJ would automatically add the closing brace when doing this change. I'm looking for the same in VS Code.

I thought I found the answer with: settings.json -> "editor.autoClosingBrackets", but nope.

Comment: I am not aware of this functionality built in to vscode.  Of course, any editor would have to assume you only want the one line of code included in the block.  If you are open to a macro solution see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get a simpler answer you could create this functionality yourself with a macro.  Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings.json:

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.createBlockForSingleLine",
      "sequence": [
        {
          "command": "type",
          "args": {
            "text": "{\n"
          }
        },
        "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
        {
          "command": "type",
          "args": {
            "text": "}"
          }
        },
      ]
    }
 ]
```

and some keybinding of your choice (in keybindings.json):

```
 { 
    "key": "alt+[",     // I used `alt+[` same as `alt+{` without the shift
    "command": "multiCommand.createBlockForSingleLine",
    "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
  },
```

Now, if you have vscode set to automatically close brackets this will unfortunately add an extra `}` where you don't want it.  So set

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "beforeWhitespace"   // or 'never'
```

to prevent that.

[image: auto create a block demo]